# Why is Slick Slider growing my images to hundreds of thousands of pixels wide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

In the snippet below, I'm unable to duplicate the issue I'm having on my website. However, I can say that I've narrowed the issue down to [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). The issue didn't happen before I started using and when I remove this particular slider, the issue goes away.

The issue is that many of the images on the page I'm working on are growing to some ridiculous heights. For example, in the slider, there's a picture of Conan O'Brien. On my site, the image grows to more than 123,000px wide.

Again, I can't duplicate the issue, but if you are aware of a specific issue and fix with Slick Slider, I'd appreciate it.

[image]

```js
$('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 800,
        slidesToShow: 1
      });

      $('.left').click(function () {
        $('.slider').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.right').click(function () {
        $('.slider').slick('slickNext');
      });
```

```css
.testimonial {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  /* slide animation */
}
.testimonial__slider {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
.testimonial .arrows {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .testimonial .arrows {
    margin-right: unset;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: unset;
  }
}
.testimonial__controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .testimonial__controls {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
.testimonial__slider .testimonial__item.active, .testimonial__slider .testimonial__item.prev-item, .testimonial__slider .testimonial__item.next-item {
  display: flex;
}
.testimonial__img {
  min-width: 40%;
}
/* .testimonial__img img {
  height: 100%;
} */
.testimonial__slider .testimonial__item {
/*   height: 100%;
  width: 100%; */
/*   display: none; */
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.testimonial__item {
  background: #F2F5F9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .testimonial__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 500px;
  }
}
.testimonial__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2.75rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.testimonial__credits {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-left: 4px solid #005fec;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}
.testimonial__name {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>


          <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial__slider">
              <div class="testimonial__controls">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                <div class="arrows">
                  <span class="testimonial__slider-control-prev left" role="button">
                    <img aria-hidden="true" src="/assets/svg/arrow-left.svg" height="25" width="25"
                      alt="Previous Slide Button">
                  </span>
                  <span class="testimonial__slider-control-next right" role="button">
                    <img aria-hidden="true" src="/assets/svg/arrow-right.svg" height="25" width="25"
                      alt="Next Slide Button">
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial__items slider">
                <div class="testimonial__item">
                  <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid"
                      src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/heroes/case-study/Case-Study-Conan-hero.jpg?w=336&h=412&auto=format&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop&fp-x=.75&fp-z=1.3&fp-y=.39"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium inventore odio sint aliquid, blanditiis officia quo ipsum tempore eligendi accusamus?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                      <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Chris Hayes</span>
                      <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">IT Director, The Conan O'Brien Show,
                        Burbank, CA</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial__item">
                  <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid"
                      src="https://sandbox-uploads.imgix.net/u/1630477471-dd0cd5b16967417586c822d6dabcb995?w=336&h=412&auto=format"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium inventore odio sint aliquid, blanditiis officia quo ipsum tempore eligendi accusamus?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                      <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Rich Sparkman</span>
                      <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">Director of Technology, Shelby
                        America</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial__item">
                  <div class="testimonial__img">
                    <img class="img-fluid"
                      src="https://sandbox-uploads.imgix.net/u/1630477587-e54d61f4eef5e36c72dccd1fc0463514?w=336&h=412&auto=format"
                      alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="testimonial__content">
                    <div class="testimonial__text">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium inventore odio sint aliquid, blanditiis officia quo ipsum tempore eligendi accusamus?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial__credits">
                      <span class="testimonial__name kicker kicker--bold">Tia Aleksandrova</span>
                      <span class="testimonial__position kicker kicker--light">IT Director, The Conan O'Brien Show,
                        Burbank, CA</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: If I execute your code it renders the image with 336 x338px. So it`s right. Maybe it's a browser bug.

Comment: Like I said, I can't duplicate the problem, but the screenshot should help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definite solution, but I had a slick carousel that was millions of pixels wide. Ultimately it was because it was inside a poorly defined flexbox. Once I turned off the flex, it was back to normal.